# selenium not sending keys but manages to click on the search bar?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i manage to find the search bar (click it) but fail to send any keys i tried everything from different elements to even using javascript but it always fails to send any keys

i tired every element i could find even tried javascript but it all failed

summery of the search bar code -

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//div)[125]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//div)[125]').clear()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span)[125]").send_keys("abc")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//div)[125]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


---
copy past of html code for the search bar
<div class="sc-bdVaJa hjHTBy sDash_fullwidth-select" style="--gap:8px; --template: initial;"><div class="ant-select sc-htoDjs iOndSp ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow ant-select-open ant-select-show-search"><div class="ant-select-selector"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true"></span><span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Search from Lahore</span></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"><span role="img" class="anticon"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="1.2em" width="1.2em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M7.41 15.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14l-6-6-6 6z"></path></svg></span></span></div></div>

<div class="ant-select sc-htoDjs iOndSp ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow ant-select-open ant-select-show-search"><div class="ant-select-selector"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true"></span><span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Search from Lahore</span></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"><span role="img" class="anticon"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="1.2em" width="1.2em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M7.41 15.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14l-6-6-6 6z"></path></svg></span></span></div>

<div class="ant-select-selector"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true"></span><span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Search from Lahore</span></div>

::before

<span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true"></span>

<input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true">

<span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_1" aria-expanded="true"></span>

<span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Search from Lahore</span>

::after 
</span>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Hi, just to confirm are you copying the entire (full) X-Path value or just the short version of it? I've had instances in the past where Selenium driver needed the full XPath string to send keys to an element

Comment: instead of find_element, can you try a WebDriverWait()?

Comment: cant share link to that page since it requires a paid login and pass

Comment: tried full xpath values they also fail

Comment: Okay, since you tried this and it failed, could I suggest assigning the XPath string in a variable eg. mystr = '(//div) [125]'. I've also noticed you encapsulated XPath in double quotes, would this make a difference?

Comment: tried the mystr thing and the double quotes did not work